# Easiest way to log visitor's ip

Tags: html, cgi

What is the easiest way to set up a page to log a visitors ip address.
I just want to record when the visitor came and from what ip.
Should I be looking at google analytics for this or is there some simple script I can throw on the page to do it.
Any pointers much appreciated,

Comment: Probably get more information if you tell up your website setup and what tools you have access to. eg Do you have your own server and what Server Side Scripting tools(eg Asp.net) do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the web server logs.